# nc connection refused even on loopback

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, netcat

I'm working on an embedded linux system, which appears to be networked correctly and is running ssh (dropbear) and rpcbind.  I'm setting up a server application on it, and every single thing I try results in my connections being refused.  Even the simplest thing like running `nc -l 5566` on the device and running `nc 192.168.1.129 5566` on my laptop results in a connection refused.  Even sitting on the same device and running `nc 127.0.0.1 5566` fails.  I've tried multiple ports both above and below 1023

So, at the moment my guess is either iptables is getting in the way, or there's a limitation about running netcat as root that I don't know. (The device is single user, so root is the only login.)  My iptables looks like this:

```
root@at91:~# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

It didn't print, but the INPUT chain is supposed to accept for anything on lo, eth0, and eth1.

I'm stumped.  Any ideas?  The device does not have SELinux.

Comment: Stop iptables abd try it again to be sure.  service iptables stop, and then run the nc command.

Comment: What runlevel are you using?  Are you sure you have networking at all?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure networking is on.  I'm connected through the console as well as multiple ssh windows.  Also I can ping the device.

Comment: The box doesn't have service, or a link to iptables in the /etc/init.d directory.  Also, all the modules are built into a monolithic kernel, so I can't unload netfilter by hand.

Comment: Can you run nmap -sP <IP address> from another box to verify that the ports are all filtered/closed on this device?  the nc command you have listed should work as root.  It does on my 2.6 kernel Red Hat box.

Comment: nmap -sP says: `Host is up (0.00033s latency).
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.30 seconds`

Comment: plain old nmap says: `Host is up (0.0064s latency).
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
22/tcp  open  ssh
111/tcp open  rpcbind

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.10 seconds`

Comment: Also, I just recompiled the kernel without netfilter support and it still doesn't work.  This must be a peculiarity of the particular angstrom distribution.

Comment: So, this is still a bit of a mystery.  I can't figure out why netcat is behaving so poorly, but my server wasn't working because the port wasn't being closed on exit.